# I want to use Google App Engine to connect to forecast.io

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Id like to use Google App Engine as a proxy for my weather app. Here is my attempt at converting the helloworld.py to do so.

```
import webapp2
import urllib2
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        api_key = 'c6cxxx'
        api_endpoint = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/'
        url = api_endpoint + api_key + '/'
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        f = opener.open("[url]" + url + "[/url]")
        self.response.write(f)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug=True)
```

All I get is a server 500
Is there a way to test GAE scripts?
What can I do to make this simple script work?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, there are ways to test GAE apps.

Are you having problems on the local dev server?  Or deployed?  What development environment are you using?

You probably should debug your code on the dev server to see what's going wrong.
If you're running on production, the exception causing your error will show up in the logs that you can view via the admin page.